# Javascript RegExp - Match String and Replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am very new to RegExp. What I am trying to do is:

I have this original query condition.

```
var strQuery = "AND i.CreatedDate BETWEEN CAST('01/01/2014' AS Date) " +
    "AND DATEADD(Day, 1, CAST('01/01/2015' AS DATE) )   " +
    "AND e.User_ID IN (-1, 1234, 3433, 9999)  " +
    "AND i.STATUS IN ('Completed')  AND o.Type IN ('Production') "
```

Now, look for the string "e.User_ID IN (" and then replace anything between the parenthesis () with new IDs String. For example.

```
var newUserIDs = "8888, 3333, 4444"

// After search and replace using RegExp.
var strQuery = "AND i.CreatedDate BETWEEN CAST('01/01/2014' AS Date) " +
    "AND DATEADD(Day, 1, CAST('01/01/2015' AS DATE) )   " +
    "AND e.User_ID IN (8888, 3333, 4444)  " +
    "AND i.STATUS IN ('Completed')  AND o.Type IN ('Production') "
```

Please help. Let me know if I am not clear since I am new to this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And why do you think you need regex for this purpose ?

Comment: Two reasons: (1) The length IDs within the User_ID IN () of the original query condition  can be varied; (2) I want to learn RegExp.  Thanks

Comment: Whoever marked my post unclear is not a nice person. I am just trying to learn... so don't be like that.

Comment: I don't think you need regex for that purpose. Regex will make it complicated. I would simply concatenate the value of  `newUserIDs` into `e.User_ID` party of query. (P.S: I didn't down voted.)

Comment: @noob, please so me an example of how to concatenate if possible.  Basically, I just want to replace the everything inside the parenthesis e.User_ID IN () Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regexp it would be like this:

```js
var strQuery = "AND i.CreatedDate BETWEEN CAST('01/01/2014' AS Date) " +
    "AND DATEADD(Day, 1, CAST('01/01/2015' AS DATE) )   " +
    "AND e.User_ID IN (-1, 1234, 3433, 9999)  " +
    "AND i.STATUS IN ('Completed')  AND o.Type IN ('Production') ";

var newUserIDs = "8888, 3333, 4444";

var newQuery = strQuery.replace(/User_ID IN \([\d, -]*\)/,"User_ID IN (" + newUserIDs + ")");

alert(newQuery);
```

You are searching for your cue, followed by 0 or more of any of the characters between [] surrounded by parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you so much @horacix.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply concatenate like this.

```js
var newUserIDs = "8888, 3333, 4444"

// After search and replace using RegExp.
var strQuery = "AND i.CreatedDate BETWEEN CAST('01/01/2014' AS Date) " +
  "AND DATEADD(Day, 1, CAST('01/01/2015' AS DATE) )   " +
  "AND e.User_ID IN (" + newUserIDs + ")  " +
  "AND i.STATUS IN ('Completed')  AND o.Type IN ('Production') "

alert(strQuery);
```

After all it's just a string.

Comment: thank you for being very helpful.  I realized that this is not working for me, but I accepted the solution anyway because it is my fault.   The entire strQuery condition could be change too, and that is the reason why I want to use RegExp.  I will try to find another solution for this, but thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Milacay: What's not working for you ? Might be you missed something in explaining your scenario. As far as I can see you are only trying to place the value of `newUserIDs` into `strQuery`. A simple string operation is enough for this purpose. Regex would complicate this and will be difficult if you want to change something in it.

Comment: I was my bad in explaining.  Sorry for the confusion.  horacix helped me with the RegExp code.